# SetAngularVelocity doesn't run immediately

Tags: javascript, box2d

I'm creating a "game" (I'm learning...) using Box2D and I have a player (a ball) and a tall box that sits beneath the player.

When the user clicks/touches/hits a key on keyboard; on the first click the player should jump up, and on the second the tall box should rotate to the right.

I've solved this easily in my input handling function:

```
var numClicks = 0;

var handleInput = function () {
    numClicks++;

    if (numClicks == 1) {
        Game.player.jump();
    }
    else if (numClicks == 2) {
        Game.launcher.launch();
    }
    else {
        Game.player.flap();
    }
};
```

As you can see, on the first click/touch/whatever, the player jumps up, on the second the launcher launches/starts rotating and after that the player flaps his wings. All of this works just to be clear.

The problem I'm having is (imo) extremely odd. What happens is that if I launch the player (by clicking) and then, BEFORE the player has reached his peak height i click again, the launcher will immediately start rotating.

HOWEVER, if I launch the player by clicking, and then wait until the player has reached his peak and started travelling down, and then click again (to start the launcher's rotation) **the launcher will not start rotating until the player touches the ground**.

What the hell is that about? I have no idea how they are even connected... If I put a console.log('Launch'); next to the call to rotate the launcher I get the console call, but the rotation refuses to start BEFORE the player touches the ground IF (and only if) I initiate the rotation AFTER the player has started travelling down again.

You can see for yourself here: http://31.192.226.6/flappy/

Try clicking twice rapidly and the "launcher" should start rotating and punch the player away. Then try clicking more slowly (specifically wait for the player to start going down) and notice what happens.

There's quite a lot of code, but the stuff related to this can be found here:

Handle input function https://github.com/powerbuoy/FlappyMatteo/blob/master/js/09-game.js line 109:
    // Handle input
    var numClicks = 0;

```
var handleInput = function () {
    numClicks++;

    if (numClicks == 1) {
        Game.player.flap();
    }
    else if (numClicks == 2) {
        Game.launcher.launch();
    }
    else {
        Game.player.flap();
    }
};
```

Player flap function https://github.com/powerbuoy/FlappyMatteo/blob/master/js/02-player.js line 25:

```
this.flap = function () {
    this.body.ApplyImpulse(new b2Vec2(0, -12 * this.energy), this.body.GetWorldCenter());

    this.energy = this.energy / 2;
};
```

Launcher launch function https://github.com/powerbuoy/FlappyMatteo/blob/master/js/02-launcher.js line 28:

```
this.launch = function () {
    this.body.SetAngularVelocity(10);
};
```

How have I gotten myself into this? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently `SetAngularVelocity()`, unlike `ApplyImpulse` or `ApplyTorque`, *will not* wake the object up so the new velocity won't take until the object wakes up.

That's why on double click it launched (object was still awake from player having touched it) but on a slower double click the object had fallen asleep and wouldn't wake up until the player touched it again.

Simply setting `body.SetAwake(true)` before the call to `SetAngularVelocity()` solved it.